# How can I pass values into MediaTypeFormatter methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following MVC TypeFormatter code and I need assistance how to:

- Pass values into this object or reference them from the controller get method

  ```
   public class ObjectSomeTypeOfFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
   {
       public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, TransportContext transportContext)
      {    
       // Method that I'm overriding where I need to access some variables defined from controller.
      }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access the Request object to get the full/relative path but it's not
>   available.

You can get it from `HttpContext.Curent.Request` and for that you need to have reference to `System.Web` asembly.

Comment: Thx for the reply.  What about passing in data to that method?

Comment: @JaJ You want to pass data from controller to formatter? If yes I think one of the way is using HttpContext.Current.Items.